# Should I store a menus collapsed state in multiple cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am working on a Control Panel that has a left column menu that has Collapsible sections  using JavaScript(jQuery) ,HTML, and Cookies.  See the image for brief idea.

In the image you can see that the `Account Information` menu is expanded/open/visible.

`Server Admin`, `Database Management`, `Domain Management`, `Mail`, and `several others` not shown in the image are Collapsed/closed/hidden

[image: menu image]

Currently I store a cookie for each menu section that tells if it is collapsed or not.  If there is 10 menu sections, that is 10 Cookies (n X menu sections) being read on every page load.

So my question is, if there was 20-30 cokies holding this information in my control panel, would it be better to instead store them as 1 cookie and thenstore the value of each menu in this one cookie, perhaps a JSON string or some other format stored in the cookie?

Would love to hear of a better way then my current.  It works now but just feel wrong.

Please help, I am by no means a Javascript expert and I am still learning JS, my background is more PHP.

Here is my code so far...

```
// jQuery Cookie plugin is not shown but is also used.


$(document).ready(function() {

    // Handle the menu state based on Click events
    $('#menu-sidebar li:has(ul) .heading').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $.cookie($(this).text().replace(/\+|-|\s/g,''), 'expanded');

            $(this).children('.open').text('-');
        }

        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $.cookie($(this).text().replace(/\+|-|\s/g,''), 'collapsed');

            $(this).children('.open').text('+');
        }
    });

    // Handle the Menu state based on current Cookie values
    $('#menu-sidebar > li').each(function() {
        var cookieName = $(this).children('.heading').text().replace(/\+|-|\s/g,'')
        var verticalNav = $.cookie( cookieName );

        if (verticalNav == 'expanded') {
            $(this).find('ul').show();
            $(this).find('.open').text('-');
        }
    });

});
```

I have added all the JavaScript and HTML + CSS on a JSFiddle page to see it in action here...  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/mvucU/

Answer (score 2):

As this is a pure javascript implementation, you should use localstorage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

As the values are not send with every request (like with cookies), it is your choice, to use a single or multiple entries. If you want to use a minimum of entries, you can use json, e. g. with this plugin https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Comment: I was thinking about using local storage, I could also do some other stuff I wanted to do like drag and drop positions and stuff that are generally too slow when using cookies.  So with local storage, it is generally faster then cookies as it doesn't have to download the cookie and then build the html based on that cookie value?

Comment: It is not generally fast, but localstorage values are saved in the browser and are not sent with your request header. Read the diveintohtml5 article. :-)